# Why does Zeitgeist use ~/.local/share/ instead of ~/.cache?

Tags: unity, home-directory, cache, zeitgeist

I have noticed that many applications like Chromium, MC, and Ubuntu One use one common `~/.cache` directory, so why doesn't Zeitgeist?

Answer (score 2):

Use it for what exactly? Persistent user data is stored in `~/.local/share`, or more aptly `$XDG_DATA_HOME`, while more transient data such as logs would be stored in `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`. Ubuntu One uses both of these directories, to store different types of data.

Comment: For example: ~/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache/index is in $XDG_CACHE_HOME and this is not log file... so I was wondering why fts.index/ is in $XDG_DATA_HOME instead of $XDG_CACHE_HOME. From my point of view this is such kind of data which is less  essential (for example for backup purposes).. changes frequently and this is recoverable data so exactly like cache meaning. @dobey maybe Zeitgeist should use both directories?

Comment: Well, the chromium cache, is cache. The fts.index is data about your data, not cache. It's probably fine to remove it if you really want to, but presumably would take a long time to recover. But if the stuff in Zeitgeist is stuff you don't care about (when you used certain things), then you should probably just not use zeitgeist.